# How to add multiple predicates of type Func<IDictionary<string, object>, bool> to a .Where clause?

Tags: c#, linq, predicate

I am having trouble figuring out how to add multiple predicates to a linq Where clause.

I have a ParsePredicateOf<IDictionary<string, object>>(item2) that takes a JsonElement. I returns a Func<IDictionary<string, object>, bool> that should be used in a where clause. At this point it only applies the last of the predicates in the foreach statement.

```
List<Func<IDictionary<string, object>, bool>> p = new List<Func<IDictionary<string, object>, bool>>();

var d1 = jsonDocument.RootElement.GetProperty("Paths").EnumerateArray();


foreach (JsonElement item in d1)
    {
       var d2 = item.GetProperty("Children").EnumerateArray();
       foreach (JsonElement item2 in d2)
       {

           var predicate = jsonExpressionParser
              .ParsePredicateOf<IDictionary<string, object>>(item2);

               p.Add(predicate);

        }
   }

            
IEnumerable<Func<IDictionary<string, object>, bool>> f = new List<Func<IDictionary<string, object>, bool>>();

foreach (Func<IDictionary<string, object>, bool> filter in p)
{
     filteredTransactions = transactionList.Where(filter).ToList();
}
```

The filteredTransaction prop

```
public List<IDictionary<string, object>> filteredTransactions { get; set; }
```

Comment: Just store the result of transactionList.Where(filter) in a variable and do the next Where call on that variable. Then after the loop call ToList on that and apply it to filteredTransactions.

Comment: what's the purpose of `f`? It's not used anywhere.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain true, it is not used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
filteredTransactions = transactionList;    
foreach (Func<IDictionary<string, object>, bool> filter in p)
{
     filteredTransactions = filteredTransactions.Where(filter);
}
```

This will effectivly chain the `Where`-statements, which results in something like this:

```
transactionList.Where(filter1).Where(filter2)...
```

Also notice that I omited the call to `ToList`, as you don't want to execute the query on every iteration, but just append the filters to the query. Only call `ToList` once when you're done building the query or when you actually want to iterate the result.

Comment: Thanks It almost does the trick. Is there a way to apply the next filter on an already filtered list?  I would like to reduce the list efter each iteration.

Comment: @KN isn't that exactly what the above does?

Comment: Yes I had an issue else where, thanks